# Which stack exchange is appropriate for information theory questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, stackexchange

There are information theory tags on at least 4 sites in this network (Stackoverflow, Math.SE, Stats.SE, and CS.SE).  Which site is most appropriate for such questions?  This topic can really bridge the scope of all those sites in some way, and it's not really clear what action to take with cross-disciplinary topics.

(A related question would be which Meta site is appropriate for this very question, but I decided Meta-Math.SE was more likely to have people able to answer the question than Meta-Stackoverflow).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It really depends on which type of question you are thinking about. The name "information theory" now refers to a rather large corpus of interdisciplinary studies that can fit into any of the sites you listed.

- For research level questions on the theoretical aspects, it should definitely go at [TCS.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com).
- For questions about its application to statistical inference or data analysis, you should ask at [Stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com).
- For implementations of the quantum versions, you should ask at [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com).
- For applications to software design, such as data compression, you should ask it at [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

And for general mathematical questions concerning information theory, you should ask right here.

Comment: If you are not sure, make your best guess and pick one of the sites. The 3K+ voters and the moderators of the fora can help you migrate the question to a more appropriate SE if your question is considered to be off-topic there.

Comment: [cs.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-theory) is another site to be considered here. Also, quantum information theory questions are now also very much on-topic on [quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For information theory of continuous processes (rather than discrete ones), I recommend [Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).